# Extending a set of linearly independent vectors to form a basis by choosing vectors from a given basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space of dimension $n\ge 1$. Let $\{v_1, \ldots, v_k\}$ be linearly independent vectors and $\{e_1\ldots, e_n\}$ be a basis.

Then does there exist a subset $E\subset\{e_1,\ldots, e_n\}$ such that $\{v_1, \ldots, v_k\}\cup E$ is a basis?

---

I attempted the following proof by inducting on $k$.

Base case holds vacuously if $k=0$. (The set of $v_i$'s is then empty.)
Now, suppose that it holds for some $k$. I prove that it holds for $k+1$.

We have that $k+1\le n$ and hence $k<n$ so that by induction hypothesis, we have a basis $\{v_1, \ldots, v_k, f_1, \ldots, f_{n-k}\}$ where $\{f_1, \ldots, f_{n-k}\}\subset \{e_1, \ldots, e_n\}$. Now, $v_{k+1} = a_1v_1 + \cdots + a_k v_k + b_1f_1+\cdots +b_{n-k}f_{n-k}$ for some scalars $a_i$, $b_i$. Now, there has to be a nonzero $b_i$ since $\{v_1, \ldots, v_{k+1}\}$ are linearly independent. Fix that $i$. Now replace $f_i$ with $v_{k+1}$. It is easily seen that the span of the set is not changed by doing this, and hence the new set is still a basis and fulfils the condition, completing induction.

**Am I correct?**

Comment: The answer is YES. Make an attempt to prove it.

Comment: you can always extending a L.I. set to a basis

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy On it!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I think I've proven it using induction! I'll edit my question, asking to check my proof. =D

Comment: FYI, the result that gives this to you is sometimes known as the Exchange Lemma. There is a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz_exchange_lemma) on the topic, but the version quoted only guarantees that the set is spanning (and makes no guarantee about linear independence). However, if you begin with a basis, then the end result will be a basis.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks for the info.

Comment: Your proof outline is correct. But depending on your teacher, and what proficiency in proving you've shown in the past, they may want you to flesh out some of the details you've handwaved here. In particular, the "easily seen" part, and that replacing $f_i$ with $v_{k+1}$ remains linearly independent. Both are true, and not hard to show, but until I have confidence that a student is not just attempting to sweep matters they are unclear on under a rug, I would want to see those details.

Comment: @PaulSinclair That this new set (after replacing $f_i$ with $v_{k+1}$) is linearly independent follows if it spans the entire $\mathbb R^n$ since it has the "correct" number of vectors. 
And, believe me I know the details I've glossed over! XD

Comment: That's fine - I was just offering a warning of a potential issue. It is up to you to decide how significant it is.

Comment: Yea, I was joking! :)